# React-native-maps lite mode don't work at Ios emulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Good afternoon everyone, I am developing an app in React native, I put the library react-native-maps to show some fixed maps in a scrollview, in android I show the coordinates with the marker but in the map moves when I try do the scroll

I'm trying with staticmap, but where I would have to leave the map in ios I'm left blank.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform, Image} from 'react-native'

import MapApp from './MapApp'

const staticMapURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap'

class PropertyListCard extends Component {
 renderMap(){
  if(Platform.OS == 'ios'){
   console.log(Platform.OS)
   return(
    <View
     style={{
      width: 500,
      height:500,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
     }}
    >
    <Image
     source={{uri: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=MyGoogleKey"}}
     style={{
      width: 200,
      height: 200
     }}
    />
    </View>
   )
  }else{
   return(
    <MapApp />
   )
  }
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
     <Text style={styles.titleText}>
      {this.props.data.direction}
     </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
     {this.renderMap()}
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.btn}
     onPress={()=>{}}
    >
     <Text
      style={styles.btnText}
     >
      Ver Vecinos
     </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  )
 }
}

const styles = {
 container: {
  flex:1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  margin: 10,
  borderRadius: 10
 },
 titleContainer:{
  height: 40,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'grey'
 },
 titleText: {
  paddingLeft: 20,
  fontSize: 17,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
 },
 mapContainer:{
  width: '100%',
  height: 200
 },
 btn:{
  height: 50,
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#008591',
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
  borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 btnText: {
  color: '#fff',
  fontSize: 17,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
 }
}

export default PropertyListCard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no support for litemode on ios
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1411#issuecomment-310380854

Comment: Thanks to answer me.
Looking for internet I found your solution, the one that you put in the link, when the probe just goes blank the hole and does not paint me anything.

Maybe I miss something.